# String variable comparison in python

Tags: python, string

I have 2 variables from a xml file;

edit:***i m sorry. i pasted wrong value ***
    x="00 25 9E B8 B9 19 " 
    y="F0 00 00 25 9E B8 B9 19 "

when i use `if x in y:` statement nothings happen

but if i use `if "00 25 9E B8 B9 19 " in y:` i get  results

any idea?

---

i am adding my full code;

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree =ET.parse('c:/sw_xml_test_4a.xml')
root=tree.getroot()

for sw in root.findall('switch'):



    for switch in root.findall('switch'):

        if sw[6].text.rstrip() in switch.find('GE01').text:
            print switch[0].text

        if sw[6].text.strip() in switch.find('GE02').text.strip():
            print switch[0].text

        if sw[6].text.strip() in switch.find('GE03').text.strip():
            print switch[0].text

        if sw[6].text.strip() in switch.find('GE04').text.strip():
            print switch[0].text
```

---

xml file detail;

```
- <switch>
  <ci_adi>"aaa_bbb_ccc"</ci_adi> 
  <ip_adress>10.10.10.10</ip_adress> 
  <GE01>"F0 00 00 25 9E 2C BC 98 "</GE01> 
  <GE02>"80 00 80 FB 06 C6 A1 2B "</GE02> 
  <GE03>"F0 00 00 25 9E B8 BB AA "</GE03> 
  <GE04>"F0 00 00 25 9E B8 BB AA "</GE04> 
  <bridge_id>"00 25 9E B8 BB AA "</bridge_id> 
  </switch>
```

Comment: ... But they have different values. Why would you expect it to be true?

Comment: `x` isn't in `y`. Can you post all of your code?

Comment: I don't believe you. x is not in y, and neither is that string.

Comment: as you see there is "00 25 9E 2C BC 8B " in "F0 00 00 25 9E B8 B9 19 "

Comment: are you sure the values for `x` and `y` that you posted are correct?

Comment: Parts of x are in y but to test this is a different thing.

Comment: Nope. I get `False` for both versions. Is there any reason that you expect either one to return `True`?

Comment: "00 25 9E 2C BC 8B " is **not** in "F0 00 00 25 9E B8 B9 19 ". Please explain why you would consider this to be true.

Comment: 'Nothing happens' means no results, and get results' means get False? Please explain

Comment: i am sorry i posted wrong values. but i edited it. problem still remains

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x = "00 25 9E 2C BC 8B"
>>> y = "F0 00 00 25 9E B8 B9 19"
>>> x in y
False
>>> "00 25 9E 2C BC 8B " in y
False
```

how exactly are you getting results?

let me explain what `in` is checking.

`in` is checking if the entire value of `x` is contained anywhere within the value of `y`. as you can see, the entire value of `x` is NOT contained in its entirety in `y`.

however, some elements of `x` are, maybe what you are trying to do is:

```
>>> x = ["00", "25", "9E", "2C", "BC", "8B"]
>>> y = "F0 00 00 25 9E B8 B9 19"
>>> for item in x:
    if item in y:
        print item + " is in " + y


00 is in F0 00 00 25 9E B8 B9 19
25 is in F0 00 00 25 9E B8 B9 19
9E is in F0 00 00 25 9E B8 B9 19
```

Comment: i edited my question i pasted wrong x value. but when i create x and y values manualy its works fine. the problem is when use x and y data from xml file as you see in my full code

Answer (score 1):

The operators in and not in test for collection membership. x in s evaluates to true if x is a member of the collection s, and false otherwise. For strings, this translates to return True if entire string x is a substring of y, else return False.

Answer (score 0):

Other than a mix-up of values in your question, this seems to work the way you want:

```
sxml="""\
<switch>
  <ci_adi>"aaa_bbb_ccc"</ci_adi> 
  <ip_adress>10.10.10.10</ip_adress> 
  <GE01>"F0 00 00 25 9E 2C BC 98 "</GE01> 
  <GE02>"80 00 80 FB 06 C6 A1 2B "</GE02> 
  <GE03>"F0 00 00 25 9E B8 BB AA "</GE03> 
  <GE04>"F0 00 00 25 9E B8 BB AA "</GE04> 
  <bridge_id>"00 25 9E B8 BB AA "</bridge_id> 
</switch>"""

tree=et.fromstring(sxml)
x="80 00 80 FB 06 C6 A1 2B"    # Note: I used a value of x I could see in the data; 
                               # your value of  x="00 25 9E B8 B9 19 " is not present...

for el in tree:
    print '{}: {}'.format(el.tag, el.text)
    if x in el.text:
        print 'I found "{}" by gosh at {}!!!\n'.format(x,el.tag)
```